# If Statement Inside Map

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, datagrid, material-ui

I currently have a DataGrid that is rendering data grabbed from my backend mongoDB. The data rendering is mapped to keys specified by the objects in the mongoDB document. In each document is a set of boolean values, and I am trying to check if any of those are true, if they are true it will render a Y in the repairsNeeded column for each row, if not, it will render an N. The main problem I am running into is where/how to check this. I have played with a few different ideas to no avail. Right now I have the repairsNeeded column for each row assigned to the document.isPowerCordDamaged (one of my booleans), which renders true or false depending on if its checked.

Code:

```
function Rounding() {
  const [cartsRounded, setCartsRounded] = useState([]);

  let navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    userCartsRounded()
      .then((response) => {
        setCartsRounded(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  const columns = [
    {
      field: "serialNum",
      headerName: "Cart Serial Number",
      width: 250,
    },
    {
      field: "pcNum",
      headerName: "Workstation Number",
      width: 250,
    },
    {
      field: "dateLastRounded",
      headerName: "Last Rounded On",
      width: 250,
    },
    {
      field: "repairsNeeded",
      headerName: "Repairs?",
      width: 100,
    },
    {
      field: "quarter",
      headerName: "Quarter",
      width: 75,
    },
  ];

  const [sortModel, setSortModel] = React.useState([
    {
      field: "dateLastRounded",
      sort: "desc",
    },
  ]);

  const rows = useMemo(
    () =>
      cartsRounded.map((row, index) => ({
        ...row,
        id: index,
        serialNum: row.cartSerialNumber,
        pcNum: row.pcNumber,
        dateLastRounded: moment(row.updatedAt).format("MM-D-YYYY"),
        repairsNeeded: row.isPowerCordDamaged,
        quarter: moment(row.updatedAt).format("Qo"),
      })),
    [cartsRounded]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <IconButton
        color="primary"
        aria-label="new rounding"
        component="span"
        onClick={() => {
          navigate("add_new_cart");
        }}
      >
        <AddCircleOutline />
      </IconButton>
      <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
        <DataGrid
          component={Paper}
          rows={rows}
          columns={columns}
          sortModel={sortModel}
          pageSize={100}
          rowsPerPageOptions={[100]}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Rounding;
```

Document Example:

```
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("61b95e447aec51d938e856cc"),
    cartSerialNumber: 'testytitit',
    pcNumber: '14124f0sdf0sfs',
    isPowerCordDamaged: false,
    isFuseBlown: false,
    isInverterBad: false,
    isInterfaceDamaged: false,
    isPhysicalDamage: false,
    otherNotes: '',
    roundedBy: '6186c13beb18d33d5088f7b2',
    createdAt: 2021-12-15T03:17:24.495Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-12-15T03:17:24.495Z,
    __v: 0
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may not be understanding the question here. But I think what you are trying to do is have the repairsNeeded field have a Y or N rather than its boolean value.

Try this.

```
const rows = useMemo(
    () =>
      cartsRounded.map((row, index) => ({
        ...row,
        id: index,
        serialNum: row.cartSerialNumber,
        pcNum: row.pcNumber,
        dateLastRounded: moment(row.updatedAt).format("MM-D-YYYY"),
        repairsNeeded: row.isPowerCordDamaged ? "Y" : "N" // short hand for if (row.isPowerCordDamaged === true) return "Y" else return "N",
        quarter: moment(row.updatedAt).format("Qo"),
      })),
    [cartsRounded]
  );
```

After looking it may be you want to return Y or N if any are true? In that case best pull it into a function.

```
const isRepairNeeded = (row) => {

  if (row.isPowerCordDamaged) return "Y";
  if (row.isFuseBlown) return "Y";
  ... rest of the ifs
  return "N"; // N is only returned if none of the if statements === true;
}

const rows = useMemo(
    () =>
      cartsRounded.map((row, index) => ({
        ...row,
        id: index,
        serialNum: row.cartSerialNumber,
        pcNum: row.pcNumber,
        dateLastRounded: moment(row.updatedAt).format("MM-D-YYYY"),
        repairsNeeded: isRepairNeeded(row) // call the function will return "Y" or "N",
        quarter: moment(row.updatedAt).format("Qo"),
      })),
    [cartsRounded]
  );
```